# Passing a select value to a link URL parameter

Tags: javascript, html, string, function

I have a `Buy` button that a user can click on to purchase a particular product.
This takes them through to a purchase form I've built.
One of the fields on that form uses a URL parameter so it knows which product the user wants to buy.

So what I want to do is to have a HTML select field somewhere on the page before (where the `Buy` button is) and allow the user to select the product there.
Then when they click on the `Buy` button, it passes the selected value through via the URL. For example:

```
// Some content here promoting the three products.

// Now I want a select field for the user to choose one of the three products, like this.

<select id="productSelect">
    <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="product3">Product 3</option>
</select>

// Then I have some more content here showing the pros/cons of each product.

// Finally, I have a buy button at the bottom of the page that takes them to the page with the purchase form. 
// Here is where I want to grab the value of the select field and pass it through via the "product" parameter like this.

<a class="button" href="/buy/?product='select value here'">Buy</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var product = document.getElementById("productSelect").value;
    event.target.setAttribute("href", "/buy?product=" + product);
});
```

This will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however can you clarify how I use this JavaScript exactly. I'm not very familiar with JavaScript, so I'm not really sure where to put it or how to use it in relation to my <a> button link.

Comment: Also, would this JavaScript affect all of my buttons? I notice getElementsByClassName references "button" of which I have several of them on the page. However I only want this one Buy button to be affected. Not all of them.